# Woocommerce cart total doesn't take account of shipping change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have added a calculate_shipping( $package ) function that seems to manage to force a shipping rate for the order but the order total still uses the original shipping cost before the alteration.

```
function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    global $woocommerce;
        $cost = 25;
        $rate = array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'label' => 'Shipping',
            'cost' => $cost,
            'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
        );
        $this->add_rate( $rate );
```

}

What do I need to do to get the order total to recalculate using the new shipping cost? I assumed this would happen automatically as you would expect but seemingly you need to force it.

WC()->cart->calculate_totals() doesn't seem to make any difference so not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should include how you did managed to force a shipping rate... with code.. how can we know you're doing it right?

Comment: @Reigel - have added the shipping code - was being retained when clicking through to checkout so clearly is storing shipping with the order

Comment: May have solved this with a different hook but can't tell cos now have an even bigger issue - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898014/woocommerce-account-side-package-rates-null